# Show hidden files, folders and drives not working - Registry Key seems broken?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I am having issues making the hidden files show up on my drives (all 3).
I have tried the default way of going through view->options->view(tab) and selecting the radio button for showing hidden files. Doesn't change anything and is gone again as soon as i re-open the settings window.

I tried the "attrib -s -h -r /s /d D:*.*" command in cmd (right click -> run as admin, type command) and get "Access denied - D:\System Volume Information"

Going in with regedit to the key [HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/Advanced] Name:Hidden - Type:REG_DWORD. The Data shows 0, supposedly 1 is show hidden, 2 is hide hidden. Trying to change it i get "Cannot edit Hidden: Error writing the value's new contents."

Any clues?

Comment: Have you tried running Cmd.exe and typing sfc /scannow and seeing if it will repair the issue you are having?

Comment: @NetworkKingPin This fixed the issue, thanks for the help

Comment: Your welcome I will put it as the answer so we can close this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always run this command with cmd.exe

```
sfc /scannow
```

A lot of the times with will fix errors like the one you are receiving. As well as a few other system related errors